# query url from mysql database using Python

Tags: python, mysql, url

I am trying to query a URL address from mysql database so that I can connect using this address and scrape a website.
however I get an error

Code:

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host=mysql_host, user=mysql_localhost_user, password=mysql_localhost_password, database=mysql_localhost_database)
cursor = cnx.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT url FROM masjid where ID =" + str(start) )
results2 = cursor.fetchone()
masjid_url = results2[0]
cursor.close()
cnx.close()
content1 = urllib2.urlopen(masjid_url).read()
```

Error:

```
masjid_url = results2[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Can your select statement return nothing? print results2 to check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may provide you a more robust management of the process:

```
# define "start" somewhere

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host=mysql_host, user=mysql_localhost_user, password=mysql_localhost_password, database=mysql_localhost_database)
cursor = cnx.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT url FROM masjid where ID =" + str(start) )
results2 = cursor.fetchone()
cursor.close()
cnx.close()
if results2 is not None:
    masjid_url = results2[0]
    content1 = urllib2.urlopen(masjid_url).read()
else:
    print('No record matches the ID "%s" or no URL available for this ID'%(start))
```

the code, changed only in the last part, provides some kind of error checking and may help you better understanding what is happening. Customize it as you like (eg. use logging).